# Code Editing over the internet

Tags: javascript, php, python, html

Is there a place that I can post code to have it looked over by others? Where they can help edit it and post suggestions on what they think would make it more efficient. You would think that I am asking about the site I am currently posting to (SO). However, I mean where people are just willing to look it over and help debug. Not where you have to have a specific question about a certain piece of your code.

Back in the day it would just be a group of buddies all working on one project in the living room of someone's house where they all brought their computers over to. My friends have lost interest in programming though.  So I am looking for something that can hook me up with other people so we can critique each other.  Is it out there? Or do I need to build it?

Comment: How about the StackExchanges' own: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Koding.com, which is currently in beta, offers you free space and basically a development server, and it's much like stack overflow. You can share code snippets and work with multiple people there.

Comment: Thank you. This does look like quite an awesome site.